Xamarin Android KeyUp event before Key is released
I am receiving a KeyUp in a Xamarin App while the key is still pressed.
This only occurs on one device out of several Android 11 devices with the same hardware and configured the same.
The device is Android 11 based with a hardware trigger which sends an F8 KeyDown when pressed.
The trigger is replaceable and still receives the KeyUp event after swapping with a trigger from a working device.
Just a second or two after pressing the trigger with a KeyDown event, the KeyUp event is received while the trigger is still pressed.
There is also no KeyUp event sent when the trigger is finally released.
The same event handlers on the same device running an native test app built with Android Studio do not produce these behaviors.
The manufacturer suggests using a BroadcastReceiver.
While using the BroadCastReceiver I am getting the exact same results between the Xamarin App Key events and the Android Studio native app.
